THREE.js How to render canvas element with no repeat?
I am trying to build a box where I can draw the images myself through a canvas element.
Here is what I have so far:
Preview
The thing is, I do not want the canvas image to repeat every face, I want to be unique and render it contantly, so if you see, the "Hello world" text is being cut after the edge, I want it to render fully in the next face.
Is that possible using a simple BoxGeometry and MeshBasic material?
This is what I have tried so far.
const ratio = devicePixelRatio;
    drawingCanvas.width = 600 * ratio;
    drawingCanvas.height = 600 * ratio;
    drawingCanvas.style.width = `${600}px`;
    drawingCanvas.style.height = `${600}px`;

    const ctx = drawingCanvas.getContext("2d");
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);

      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.font = "80px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("Hello World", 600 / 2 - 15, 600 / 2 - 15);
    }

    const map = new THREE.CanvasTexture(
      drawingCanvas,
      THREE.UVMapping,
      THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
      THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
    );

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map,
      })
    );```

